# Check if a column is null in relationship, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I try to check if a column from a relationship table is null, . But with my current code I get an error.
The column is `"best_match"` in the second `whereNotNull`.

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry
>   for table "questions"↵LINE 1:

```
$questions = Model::whereNotNull('question_id');

if($excepted_questions){
   $questions->whereNotIn('id', $excepted_questions);
}

$questions->where('votes', '!=' , $confidence_specs->votes)
   ->orWhere('weight', '!=' , $confidence_specs->weight)
   ->with('questions')
   ->inRandomOrder();

//HERE I try to check if that column is null or not
if($confidence_specs->best_match){ // this can be true / false ,if is true I check if that column is null
   $questions->whereNotNull('questions.best_match');
}

$questions->limit($nr_of_questions)
   ->get();
```

[image]

Comment: Use $questions = Question::whereNotNull('question_id');

Comment: Please read again the description. The problem is from the second whereNotNull from code.

Comment: dump $questions->toSql() and see what's the query.

Comment: give $questions->whereNotNull('best_match'); and try

Comment: I updated the question. That's how it looks , but there I don't use whereNotNull for best_match.

Comment: dump $questions->toSql()

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `whereHas` to use `where` statement with the relationship model or you must have joined the table.

Otherwise just using `where` statement won't work on multiple tables.

For more information check the docs [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

So your query should have been

```
if($confidence_specs->best_match) { 
    $questions->whereHas('questions', function($query) {
       $query->whereNotNull('best_match');
    });
}
```

`with` will just eager loads the model it doesn't let you perform MySQL query on it.